# Display:none does not seem to be working all html elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to make this part of the form disappear by putting it in a `div` and the `id` = loan

To troubleshoot I put `TESTTEXT1` in after the div element, and it does what I want (disappears when user clicks a radio button),However `TESTTEST2` and beyond does not seem to be affected by the user's action. Does anyone know why this could be?

HTML:

```html
<header>


<script>
 function checkA(){
 document.getElementById('loan').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('assigned').style.display='block';
  }
function checkL(){
 document.getElementById('assigned').style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('loan').style.display='block';
}
</script> 

</header>

<body>

<table>
<td>
  <input type="radio" onclick='checkA()' name="toloan" id="0" value="0"/> <label for="0">To assign</label>
  <input type="radio" onclick='checkL()' name="toloan" id="1" value="1"/> <label for="1">To loan</label>
</td>


<div id="loan">
  TESTTEXT1
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="borrowing_month">Borrowing date</label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <select name="borrowing_month" id="borrowing_month">
        
          <option value ='1' selected="selected">
            TEST
          </option>
       </select>
      <select name="borrowing_day" id="borrowing_day">
        
          <option value="2" selected="selected">
      </select>
      <select name="borrowing_year" id="borrowing_year">
          <option value="3" selected="selected">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="return_month">Return date</label>
    </th>
    <td>
      <select name="return_month" id="return_month">
          <option value="4" selected="selected">
          </option>
      </select>
      <select name="return_day" id="return_day">
          <option value="5" selected="selected">
      </select>
      <select name="return_year" id="return_year">
          <option value="6" selected="selected">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>

</table>
</body>
```

OK I tried to remove all the php as requested.

Comment: can you make a working demo with the html/css/js? we don't need the PHP.

Comment: Dropping that text node in as a direct child of a `<tr>` results in invalid markup. Only `<th>` and `<tr>` elements should be direct children of `<tr>`.

Comment: do your css rules have !important? doing inline css on an element with an id/class rule with !important won't override it

Comment: @Pointy has it.  That TESTTEXT2 is going to get bumped outside the table because it's in an invalid location.  Table text needs to be in a `<th>` or a `<td>`.  (Also there's no `<table>` tag, I just noticed; I'm not sure what the browser will make of that, but it probably isn't good)

Comment: Please copy just the frontend code from Chrome/ Firefox DevTools, paste it inside https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=N2BQELqaaz and then save your snippet and share the link here.

Comment: `<tr>` shouldn't be a child of `<div>`, the only permitted parents of `<tr>` are `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>`. If you can, create a Stack Snippet with the page icon that contains `< >` in the editor before you create a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanielBeck points out, there is no table-wrapper, so I would try changing the `<div id="loan">` to `<table id="loan">`.

You'll have to change the closing tag from `</div>` to `</table>`, of course, and it will change your javascript a little:

```
function checkA() {
  document.getElementById('loan').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('assigned').style.display = 'table';
}

function checkL() {
  document.getElementById('assigned').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('loan').style.display = 'table';
}
```

Comment: Sorry the HTML is under a table-wrapper but higher up on the code so I did not include it. I edited the code to a stripped down version so that it is easier to understand I hope

Comment: But if I understand correctly, I can not put a div element underneath a table element. Which means that to make this work I must split the content into two tables

Answer (score 1):

Let it be known that **you can not use div elements inside table-wrappers**. If you wish to use the div element to add CSS to only part of a table. It is better to add a ID to the table head/row/data or just make a new table altogether for that specific part of the table.